# Cannot install react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons in visual studio code

Tags: react-native, npm-install

I'm trying to use Ionicons in react native with vscode. But when I type the command:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons
```

I receive the error:

```
PS C:\ReactNProjects\test230215> npm install react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I tried removing the nod_modules folder and tried to install again but still nog success. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `react-native-vector-icons` instead of `react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons` as [docs](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation). After following instructions you can simply use it by importing.

Comment: This was what worked for me thank you very much. I also had to clear the cache before the icons were visible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of your npm command?

I found this command: npm install --save react-native-vector-icons

(source: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#installation)

And then you import react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons at the top of your js/ts file(s)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this also worked at some point.